# Getting an attribute from an object inside an arraymap

Tags: android

I'm creating a class called "partite", and this is the code

```
public class Partita {

    String HT;      //HomeTeam
    String AT;      //AwayTeam
    String dataP;   //dataPartita
    int HG;         //HomeGoal
    int AG;         //AwayGoal
    String FTR;     //Full time result

    public Partita(){
        this.HT = "";
        this.AT = "";
        this.dataP = "";
        this.HG = 0;
        this.AG = 0;
        this.FTR = "";
    }

    public Partita(String HT, String AT, String dataP, int HG, int AG, String FTR) {
        this.HT = HT;
        this.AT = AT;
        this.dataP = dataP;
        this.HG = HG;
        this.AG = AG;
        this.FTR = FTR;
    }
}
```

In the main activity I'm creating an `ArrayList`, putting a list of some "Partita" object, with attributes come from a json file, and then I create an `ArrayMap` and put the `ArrayList` inside, like this

```
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++) {

          JSONObject jsonPart = arr.getJSONObject(i);
          partite.add(new Partita(jsonPart.getString("HomeTeam"), 
          jsonPart.getString("AwayTeam"),jsonPart.getString("Date"), 
          jsonPart.getInt("FTHG"), jsonPart.getInt("FTAG"), 
          jsonPart.getString("FTR")));

          partitemap.put(i, partite.get(i));

          Log.i("partita", partite.get(i).HT + " " + partite.get(i).HG + ":" + partite.get(i).AG + " " + partite.get(i).AT);

                }
```

How can I use the ArrayMap instead of ArrayList to get the attributes of an object and use it?

Comment: Note: if you use descriptive variable names, you don't need comments.

Comment: Also, what happens when you run your code? Do you get an error? If so, what is it?

Comment: no, this code is working, but into the Log.i I'm putting the attributes of the object from the ArrayList, and I want to pick them up from the ArrayMap but I don't know how

Comment: Please show a **complete** code example. Your current code has several undefined variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this instead (edited):

```
          for (int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++) {
              JSONObject jsonPart = arr.getJSONObject(i);
              partitemap.put(i, new Partita(jsonPart.getString("HomeTeam"), 
                                            jsonPart.getString("AwayTeam"),
                                            jsonPart.getString("Date"), 
                                            jsonPart.getInt("FTHG"), 
                                            jsonPart.getInt("FTAG"), 
                                            jsonPart.getString("FTR")
                                           )
              );
              Log.d("tag", partitemap.get(i).HT);
          }
```

Comment: i need to pick up and use the attributes, not only put them into the ArrayMap

Comment: @GabrielePuia check the changes and let me know if you need anything.